# Using the same variable between different Python Runs

Tags: python, redis, multiprocessing, shared-memory, mmap

I have a script like this

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for bag in range(num_bags):
        feats = pd.read_csv(f"feats_{bag}.csv")
        ... # some logic
```

As you can see, it repetitively reads data from a set of files. Each `"feats_{bag}.csv"` file is repetitively being read from disk `num_epoch` times. This slowed down the program. I preloaded all of the data at once, which helped significantly. In the following script, each `"feats_{bag}.csv"` is only read once.

```
all_feats = [pd.read_csv(f"feats_{bag}.csv") for bag in range(num_bags)]
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for bag in range(num_bags):
        feats = all_feats[bag]
```

The issue with the above program is the hight memory usage, as it loads all the data at once. The `all_feats` variable roughly takes 20GB of memory. I have about 64 GB of memory, so I am limited to executing the program 3 times simultaneously. As all the runs use the same set of `feats`, I thought there must be a way to load the data (`all_feats` variable) once and use it in all runs simultaneously for more than 3 runs.

In other words, with only taking 20GB of storge for the `all_feats` variable, I want to run many scripts (that all use the `all_feats` variable), by sharing the `all_feats` variable between them.

I've looked up `mmap` and Python `multiprocessing.shared_memory`. Although both allow sharing of a variable between processes, they seem unsuitable for my problem. For example for Shared Memory, I tried the following:

```
# SharedMemory Server
all_feats = [pd.read_csv(f"feats_{bag}.csv") for bag in range(num_bags)]
sl = shared_memory.ShareableList(all_feats, name='all_feats')
```

```
# SharedMemory Client
all_feats = shared_memory.ShareableList(name='MyList')
print(id(all_feats), all_feats)
```

However, After running the server, when I run the client multiple times, the id of `all_feats` seems to be different with every run, meaning they have used different memory locations, thus taking up more memory than what I intended again.

Some other ideas I had for speed up:

- Load all_feats files in memory using Redis or some other in-memory database. Then use the first approach again. i.e. load only the current needed feats at each iteration, but this time from Redis.

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for bag in range(num_bags):
        feats = redis.get("bag_i")
        ... # some logic
```

I'm hoping reading from memory (redis) instead of the disk, gives a reasonable speed boost, Although not as much as preloading all the data in Python.

- <s>Divide the feats in chunks, and preload them part by part.</s> won't work.

In summary, I'm looking for a way to use the **same variable** in different runs of the same/different Python scripts. Note that I don't want to use duplicates of the variable. Thus, using a file in memory, and reading the file does not help me. All scripts only read the variable and do not change it.

Can `shared_memory` solve this? then why did it assign different IDs for the `all_feats` variable in different runs?

Comment: Your trying to have a "global" variable `all_feats` that 3 python scripts can access. You're overcomplicating, you can probably make do with threading, a single program that has the loaded data in a variables and that launches different processes that can access that variable.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the point about different memory locations between runs. As long as the program has terminated at the end of a run, of course it's possible to get new memory allocations on the next run, but the old ones are cleared up at the end of the previous run. It's not stacking data into RAM between runs. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @Daviid The scripts are for training a PyTorch model and are not run at the same time. Suppose I want to start a run now, and the next one 2 hours later. Therefore I can't use a single Python program that creates 3 threads and passes the `all_feats` variable at the same time. (I'm also not sure if PyTorch is ok with multithreading, it probably is, but I have to look into that)

Comment: @roganjosh I might be missing something here but doesn't getting new memory locations mean that each run is using a duplicate of the `all_feats` variable? Using duplicates means that the runs are again using ~40GB of memory, instead of ~20GB which I'm hoping for.

Comment: Ok, so nothing happens to the server between runs of the client. It's just sat in a waiting state for the next request?

Comment: @roganjosh Exactly, I used a `while True: sleep(1)` statement, to keep it running. But when I run the client code multiple times, I get different IDs.

Comment: We could be quibbling over terminology here because you're variously talking about servers, scripts, clients etc. but it actually matters because I'm trying to visualise what you're actually doing. I don't understand what `epoch` is because it looks like a pointless outer loop, and I don't know where `i` comes from in the second code block. There might be an easy solution for this but we need to be on the same page

Comment: Sorry that the post wasn't clear. The `epoch` outer loop in the first code block is the root cause of the slow performance. Because It makes each each file to be read from the disk not just once, but `num_epoch` times. (Added some explanations to the post about this)
As for the client and server, I was talking about the two code blocks I put with these two names. By `server` I meant the script that defines the shared memory, and by client, I meant the script that accesses the shared memory using its name.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it, thanks. There's a lot of things to try pull together here. I will try work on an answer but not sure if I will have enough time to type it all up right now

Answer (score 0):

Why not just reverse the order of the loops:

```
    for bag in range(num_bags):
        feats = pd.read_csv(f"feats_{bag}.csv")
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    ... # some logic
```

Comment: Thanks! But I can't do this, because that's just the logic of the code. For training deep learning models, in each epoch, the model should work with all the data, which are `feats` here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a manager of your data. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) you can create a manager to hold the data and then provide the manager-object to all sub-processes. The data is then shared across all processes, but is residing in the manager. So you need 2x your 20GB - 20GB for the main process creating the manager, and another 20GB for the manager itself.

Use the following to share your data:

```
all_feats = [pd.read_csv(f"feats_{bag}.csv") for bag in range(num_bags)]
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
shared_data = manager.Namespace()
shared_data.all_feats = all_feats

del all_feats  # might help freeing some memory
```

Your processes are started using the following lines, providing the manager-reference.

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(shared_data,))
p.start()
p.join()
```

Now you can read directly from the pandas-DataFrame `shared_data.all_feats` without having to copy it.